# How can we communicate with server in QML?

Tags: qt, xmlhttprequest, request, httprequest, qml

I am developing a client-side application, and I want to communicate with a server. Which requests are there? Which one is the best way?

I am using Qt and I want solution for QML.

Comment: i want information about http/GET and http/POST, how can i add parameter to this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML provides a partial implementation of XMLHttpRequest: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativeglobalobject.html

If this is not sufficient, you can write an extension to use Qt's C++ network classes instead.